# Mixed content error in chrome

Tags: java, apache, google-chrome, ssl, https

I am getting this error in chrome:

> The page at 'https://www.SERVER_ONE.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://SERVER_TWO.com/someAPI'. This request has been blocked; the
>   content must be served over HTTPS.

Both SERVER_ONE, and SERVER_TWO are owned by me.
But the problem is that the HTTPS certificate I hold is only for server_ONE.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this error, can I introduce some mode_proxy in SERVER_TWO to redirect all https to http, or is there any way in which I can write some proxy in java side and put it on server_one which can act as an adapter for https to http?

Please guide me with some snippet code if any such adapter code is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just enable https on server2 and change your call from http to https.

For the certificate you can use https://letsencrypt.org/ for server2 for free.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call directly SERVER_TWO, you should configure or implement a proxy on SERVER_ONE so that every call can be done over HTTPS.

Comment: Can you please help me out with this solution with some snippet or sample example in java. Thanks

Comment: @Ninja it's full of tutorial out there, you could use jetty and run it as a standalone like in this tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/http-and-https-proxies-jetty but if you already have a tomcat instance you could implement a servlet within your current application I suggest to use https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet